# clojure way to organize code for displaying data of a program

Tags: model-view-controller, data-structures, clojure

My program consists of a list of nested `defrecords` as data: each entry of the list is a `defrecord` that has several fields which contain `defrecords` themselves. The definition of these is in a seperate file `data.clj`. I wanted to write another file `view.clj` which should render this data.

In this particular example not all of the data structure is needed, some fields of the nested `defrecords` shouldn't be displayed. Other fields need some kind of preprocessing before they can be displayed (they store dates for example and they should be formatted in a certain way).

What would be the idomatic way to organize such a program? Would it be better to have the `data.clj` preprocess the data and give the `view.clj` a generic map to display for this *view* of the data. Or should the view take the whole datastructure and only extract the parts that it needs for displaying. Also to mention, since I'm still in the early development, the datastructure is far from final, so there could be some major changes.

Answer (score 0):

Give the entire dataset to the view, and let the view decide what to display.

Also, write the data processing code as a pure function; that way, you can easily move it later if you need to.